# Mongo DB client cannot be closed (Express, Node.js, MongoClient)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have methods like this one to handle API requests from FE:

```
routerPeople.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  client.connect((err, client) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(err);
    const dbTarget = client.db(db).collection(collection);
    try {
      dbTarget.deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) });
      res.status(200).json({ msg: msges.success });
      client.close();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).json({ msg: msges.error });
    }
  });
});
```

Mongo client is initiated like this:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
const db = "app";
const collection = "people";
const uri = `mongodb://localhost:27017/admin`;
```

Even when client.close() is called in the code, connection is still up and running. I have tested it via client.isConnected() method. Req/Res works fine...

I am also getting these warnings in console (because I am connecting to already connected DB in additional requests.)

```
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
```

```
"mongodb": "^3.3.2",
```

Many thanks

Comment: When/how do you call `isConnected()`? `close` is an asynchronous operation and might not have completed when you try to check the connection.

Comment: Almost everywhere, I also gets these option warning in the console (The reason for that should be, that I am still connected to DB):
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported